# How to split this string into an array

Tags: javascript, regex, string

If I have a string like below and It is not static every time.

```
 var str = "#a
            b
            c
            _
            ele1
            ele2
            #d
            e
            f
            _
            ele3
            ";
```

from the above string I want to retrieve an array like below

```
     arr = [ "#a
               b
               c
              _",
             "ele1",
             "ele2",
             "#d
               e
               f
              _",
             "ele3"
           ]
```

The criterion is: everything between # and _ as a single item; every line outside those delimiters is a separate item.

How can I do that.Any idea.... Please use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JLwbf/) fiddle.

Comment: What is the ground on which you have split the string above??

Comment: Can you describe how it should split? Before and after every word starting with "ele"?

Comment: May be you want to split it using space, if so try to str.split(" ")

Comment: @Prathap Reddy SV, I think your question was not obvious and Sunil Kumar's question is logical. You shouldn't comment like that, seems you know each other personally, just my guess.

Comment: I know but everyone is not capable of doing the same guess and he was trying to help you so ... !

Comment: Yes you are right and we are not right always.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for your response. There "ele" is dummy text I have taken. I am able to split the string with "\n". But i am unable to retrieve the array as I want from my method. :-(

Comment: @Heera :-) I am removing my comments. But not for upvote. I have understood the depth of your words.

Comment: @ Prathap Reddy SV, well done. May lord bless us all.

Comment: I think the criterion is: everything between `#` and `_` as a single item; every line outside those delimiters is a separate item.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, Exactly. Please have a look at the Joseph's answer. That is 70% done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the criteria in my comment under the question:

```
var str = "#a\nb\nc\n_\nfoo\nbar\n#d\ne\nf\n_";
var re = /((?:#[^_]*_)|(?:^.*$))/mg;
var result = str.match(re);
console.log(result);
// [ '#a\nb\nc\n_', 'foo', 'bar', '#d\ne\nf\n_' ]
```

Regexp explanation: a match is either everything from `#` to `_` - `(?:#[^_]*_)` - or everything on a single line - `(?:^.*$)`.

**EDIT:** due to whitespace... a bit different strategy:

```
var str = $('#a').text();
var re = /^\s*((?:#[^_]*_)|(?:.*?$))/mg;
var result = [], match;
while ((match = re.exec(str))) {
  result.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(result);​
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JLwbf/5/) I have checked with another criteria. But it is failed in some cases. Please check.

Comment: OK, whitespace trouble. I modified my response accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Again, given the criteria in the comment this works

```
var arr = str.match(/(?:#([^_]*)_|([^#_\s])+)/g)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhDPj/1/

And to explain the regex

- `#([^_]*)_` - find anything that isn't `_` that falls between a `#` and a `_` ( `*` means even empty strings are captured)
- `([^#_\s])+` - find anything that isn't `#`, `_` or whitespace ( `+` means only non-empty strings are captured)
- `(?: | )` - find either of the above (but non-capturing as the above expressions already capture the strings needed)
- `/   /g` - global match, to return all matches in the string rather than just the first one

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please check the fiddle. It is not giving me any result.

Comment: I just edited the fiddle and changed the link above and it should work now - I was logging the wrong thing

Comment: Made my day :-) There should be made my day tag in stackoverflow.com

Comment: aww, shucks... and people say the web is where people go to be anonymous and nasty

Answer (score 3):

are the whitespaces intentional?

try this instead:

```
<div id ="a">#abc_ele1ele2#def_ele34</div>​
```

script:

```
var str = $('#a').text();
var result = str.match(/(#[^_]*_)|([^#][^\d]*\d{1,})/g)
console.log(result)

EXPLANATION:
string.match()      - returns an array of matches
#[^_]*_             - finds anything that begins with # and ends with _ and with anything but _ in between
[^#][^\d]*\d{1,}    - finds anything with that does NOT start with #, followed by 0 or more non-numeric characters,  and ends with at least one digit
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JLwbf/4/): check your console

this will still run with all those whitespaces. you MUST be clear with your split rules.

Comment: @Heera Thanks and From me also

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for your help. But the text "ele" is just dummy text. It will not come all the time.. I am sorry, I did not mention in the Question.

Comment: @Joseph I have tried changing the regular expression to `str.match(/#[^_]*_|[a-zA-Z0-9]{?}\n{1,}/g)` But still it is skipping them

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = str.match(/(#?[a-z]+[0-9_]+?)/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

try split:

```
arr = str.split("_");
```

Comment: I appreciate that @ Prathap Reddy SV.